# Issues with Today Widget extension

Tags: ios, swift, ios-app-extension

I have a Today Widget for my app, however I have been told about an issue with it.

Basically, what seems to be happening (I can't test this for myself) is that the widget will sometimes just display 'unable to load' and other times it will just display with a height of 0.

I can't really see why this is happening. I've tested it out on my device and the simulator for weeks now and have never ran into this issue.

I was wondering if it could possibly be down to the refresh code:

```
    func widgetPerformUpdateWithCompletionHandler(completionHandler: ((NCUpdateResult) -> Void)!) {
    // Perform any setup necessary in order to update the view.

    var defaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.AffordIt")
    var newCheck = defaults.boolForKey("new")

    if newCheck == true {
        completionHandler(NCUpdateResult.NewData)
    } else {
        completionHandler(NCUpdateResult.NoData)
    }
}
```

'newCheck' is true whenever something changes within my app that needs to be displayed in the widget.

Does anyone know what the possible causes of these issues are?

Answer (score 2):

"unable to load" message appears if your extension crashes often. You can try to re-enable it by removing and adding the extension again.

Comment: I released an update to my app to address another bug. I didn't modify the widget code at all and it seems to have fixed it anyway so maybe it is an iOS 8 bug. The 'unable to load' error still displays if the user tries to use the widget without ever having opened the app yet though. So is there any way of changing this message?

Comment: @user3746428 you can create a `NSUserDefaults` key (Google how to read shared defaults between app and widget) that is a simple `BOOL` indicating whether your app has been run first. Check the key when your app starts and if it's `false` display a message telling the user to run the app first.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using your own view controller and xib instead of using storyboard? If yes, it is probably that you didn't set the preferredContentSize in your view controller.

try to put the following code in the init function of ur view controller:

```
    self.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 100);
```

I have just began the extension programming today so I am not sure is it really helpful for u or not. Here is the result in my own widget:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Press **Edit** button in today extensions
2. **Remove** your extension
3. **Add** your extension again.